# Adding logging to specific existing spring boot endpoints

Tags: rest, spring-boot, logging, endpoint

We have several spring boot Rest APIs with hundreds of endpoints.

Are there any tools or libraries that we can use to monitor specific endpoints, logging the request, response, and timings to a custom database?

Any in particular that can be attached to running services already?

I've heard of Actuator, AOP, AspectJ, but I'm not sure it's what we want?

Thanks

Comment: this is a good question

Comment: if you are not sure what you want, then how could we know?

Comment: just use a webfilter

Answer (score 0):

You can create an aspect that logs  enter/exit logs and time execution for each method of given packages.

To calculate time execution, you can use spring [`Stopwatch`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html). However, you have to be careful to the performance impacts. (This class isn’t recommended for production environment)

```java
    import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class LoggingAspect {

        private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        /**
         * Pointcut that matches all services and Web REST endpoints.
         */
        @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)" +
            " || within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
        public void springBeanPointcut() {
            // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
        }

        /**
         * Pointcut that matches all Spring beans in the application's endpoint packages.
         */
        @Pointcut("within(your.pack.num1..*)" +
            " || within(your.pack.num2..*)" +
            " || within(your.pack.num3..*)")
        public void applicationPackagePointcut() {
            // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
        }

        /**
         * Advice that logs methods throwing exceptions.
         *
         * @param joinPoint join point for advice
         * @param e exception
         */
        @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()", throwing = "e")
        public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
            log.error("Exception in {}.{}() with cause = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause() : "NULL");
        }

        /**
         * Advice that logs when a method is entered and exited.
         *
         * @param joinPoint join point for advice
         * @return result
         * @throws Throwable throws IllegalArgumentException
         */
        @Around("applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()")
        public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
          StopWatch stopWatch;
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                stopWatch= new StopWatch();
                stopWatch.start();
                log.debug("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
            }
            try {
                try{
                Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
                }finally{
                stopWatch.stop();
                }
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug("Exit: {}.{}() with result = {} and execution time {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                        joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), result,stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
                }
                return result;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                log.error("Illegal argument: {} in {}.{}()", Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a separate solution that can be aimed at existing endpoints? 
or does it have to have the source code modified/annotated for it to work?

Comment: This solution uses Aspect oriented programming. 
You don’t need to alter your existing code. You need just to add the package you want to intercept to the Aspect Pointcut.